# SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate, certificate verify failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ssl, openssl

I am very new to Ruby on Rails and am trying to get a simple weather app to run but I have having a problem when trying to pull data from Forecast.io. When i go to it on my machine I get the following error:

**SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed**

**Main_Controller.rb**

```
class MainController < ApplicationController  
  def index
  @main =  Main.getWeather();
  end
end
```

**Main.rb**

```
require 'forecast_io'
require 'openssl'
class Main < ActiveRecord::Base
  #OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
  ForecastIO.configure do |configuration|
    configuration.api_key = '[my_api_key]'
  end  

  def self.getWeather()
    forecast = ForecastIO.forecast(32.6781248,-83.178297)
    return forecast
  end
end
```

Application Trace:

```
    app/models/main.rb:12:in `getWeather'
    app/controllers/main_controller.rb:4:in `index'
```

Framework Trace:

```
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:918:in `connect'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:918:in `block in connect'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb:52:in `timeout'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:918:in `connect'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:862:in `do_start'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:851:in `start'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1367:in `request'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1126:in `get'
    faraday (0.9.1) lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:80:in `perform_request'
    faraday (0.9.1) lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:40:in `block in call'
    faraday (0.9.1) lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:87:in `with_net_http_connection'
    faraday (0.9.1) lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:32:in `call'
    faraday (0.9.1) lib/faraday/request/url_encoded.rb:15:in `call'
    faraday (0.9.1) lib/faraday/rack_builder.rb:139:in `build_response'
    faraday (0.9.1) lib/faraday/connection.rb:377:in `run_request'
    faraday (0.9.1) lib/faraday/connection.rb:140:in `get'
    forecast_io (2.0.0) lib/forecast_io.rb:47:in `get'
    forecast_io (2.0.0) lib/forecast_io.rb:23:in `forecast'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
    activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
    activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
    activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
    activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
    activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
    activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
    activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
    activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
    activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
    activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
    activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
    activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
    activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
    activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
    activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
    activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
    activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
    actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:232:in `block in action'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `call'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `dispatch'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `call'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:73:in `block in call'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:678:in `call'
    rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
    rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
    rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
    rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
    rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
    activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
    activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
    activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
    activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
    railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
    railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
    activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
    activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
    activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
    railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
    rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
    rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
    activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
    rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:84:in `call'
    rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
    railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
    railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
    rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
    rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
    rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Env Dump:

```
    GATEWAY_INTERFACE: "CGI/1.1"
    HTTP_ACCEPT: "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"
    HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING: "gzip, deflate, sdch"
    HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: "en-US,en;q=0.8"
    HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL: "max-age=0"
    REMOTE_ADDR: "127.0.0.1"
    REMOTE_HOST: "127.0.0.1"
    SERVER_NAME: "localhost"
    SERVER_PROTOCOL: "HTTP/1.1"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by installing OpenSSL and pointing my SSL_CERT_PATH to the downloaded location.